# Don't include blank fields in GET request emitted by Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

On my Django-powered site, I have a search page with several optional fields. The search page is a Django form, and my view function is the typical:

```py
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        return form.display_results(request)

    return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form})
```

Form.display_results() uses the fields that are provided to query the DB and render a response. My search.html includes:

```
<form action="/search/" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Render the form fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset form" />
</form>
```

Since most searches will have several blank fields, I'd like not to include them in the GET request emitted by the submit button on search.html.  Current searches look something like:

```
http://mysite/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=blah&optional_field1=&optional_field2=&optional_field3=oohIWantThisOne
```

And I'd like them to look like:

```
http://mysite/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=blah&optional_field3=oohIWantThisOne
```

Of course, I have a several more fields. This would be nice to have because it would make search URLs more easily human-parsable and sharable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use jQuery with an button trigger. Give the form and submit button ids.

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    $("#form_id").submit();
});
```

That (or something similar) should remove all the empty fields before the submit.

Comment: The problem with this method is, if the form doesn't submit for some reason (e.g. validation), those inputs will be gone. Maybe you could attach the function directly to the `submit` method.

Comment: Right - the browser submits all successful controls on the form (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) so the only way this will work is using Javascript of some sort to remove or deactivate the unnecessary controls.  Also note that if you're planning to pass these URLs around, you really don't want your CSRF tokens in them.  CSRF tokens are ignored for GET requests, but it's still unnecessary and a bad practice.

Comment: I really think the other solution, to POST the form, is cleaner.

Comment: Hmm.  And then insert the relevant parameters into the response URL, and make sure that URL can be fulfilled later?  Yeah, there's nothing wrong with that either.  I guess I meant that 'the only way this will work with a GET request is using Javascript...'.

Comment: This function had no effect on my site. I checked the js console and there are no errors. I also tested by calling the function manually and it does submit the form as expected. Still, the URL contains the empty `GET` parameters. Any ideas?

Using jquery version 1.12.4 (via Google CDN).

Answer (score 2):

You could also POST the form. Then build the search url and redirect with empty values removed.

Comment: The annoying thing about using `POST` is that one cannot share a link with pre-filled search parameters, not even between Views on the site (at least without javascript tricks). This is annoying.

Comment: So use the POST data to build the url parameters, ignoring empty ones. Then the url is bookmarkable.

Answer (score 2):

*disclaimer: This is a very old question, and the only one I could find that matches the problem I ran into. It's entirely possible that my solution didn't exist at the time, and an even better way has since been added.*

I'm using Django 3.2. I didn't want to use js/jQuery, nor did I want to use a POST form, so here's what I came up with. In a nutshell, it just checks the GET data to see if there are any default values present, and simply redirects to a URL that doesn't have them.

In your view:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def myView(request):
    if not is_clean_form(request.GET):
        return redirect(whatever_url_path + clean_url_parameters(request.GET))
    else:
        # whatever your view does normally
```

Helper functions (consider making these static methods of your Form class, to keep all that type of stuff together):

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

# fields and their default value (eg. empty string)
default_form_values = [
    ("some_field_name", ""),
    # ...
]

def is_clean_form(form_dict):
    for field, default_value in default_form_values:
        if field in form_dict and form_dict[field] == default_value:
            return False
    return True

def clean_url_parameters(form_dict):
    return "/?" + urlencode([
        (field, form_dict[field]) for (field, default_value) in default_form_values
        if field in form_dict and form_dict[field] != default_value
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Hide empty fields from GET form](https://www.billerickson.net/code/hide-empty-fields-get-form/) by Bill Erickson:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // Remove empty fields from GET forms
  // Author: Bill Erickson
  // URL: http://www.billerickson.net/code/hide-empty-fields-get-form/

  // Change 'form' to class or ID of your specific form
  $("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(":input").filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return true; // ensure form still submits
  });

  // Un-disable form fields when page loads, in case they click back after submission
  $("form").find(":input").prop("disabled", false);
}
```